# Intersection of two lines

Tags: matlab, line, intersection

If I have two lines:

```
line1 = [1 2; ...
         5 4];
line2 = [1 7; ...
         4 2];
```

[image]

How Can I get the intersection point of any two line like the previous ones ?

Comment: If you always have the lines in this format, it should not be too hard to write out the formula that gives you the solution.

Comment: Well, this IS equivalent to a system of TWO linear equations, in two unknowns. If there was any way you could possibly solve those equations, then it might be possible. I wonder? Maybe it is time for you to return to high school algebra?

Comment: like the one here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line-line_intersection

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you detect where two line segments intersect?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/563198/how-do-you-detect-where-two-line-segments-intersect)

Answer (score 2):

This is more a math question than a programming one:

An equation for a line is `y = ax+b`

to find `a`, you do

```
a = (y2-y1)/(x2-x1)...
```

or in your case:

```
a = (line1(1,2)-line1(2,2))/((line1(1,1)-line1(2,1));

a = 0.5
```

then you find `b` with a point in your line, i.e.:

```
y = 0.5x+b --> 2 = 0.5(1)+b --> b = 1.5;

y1 = 0.5x+1.5
```

Do the same thing for the other line.

Then do `y1 = y2` to solve.